# Term to describe the written, paragraph-form part of a report

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for the written, paragraph-form parts of a paper/report/etc., as opposed to the figures, equations, and their captions?  I'm reviewing a technical report for a colleague who has put a lot of numerical data in the written part, making it a bit tedious to read.  I want to suggest that he summarize this numerical data in a separate table or chart, e.g.:

> There are a lot of numbers in the written parts; you should summarize them in a table.

I feel like there should be a better word for "written part" however.  The word "copy" is close, but seems to be used specifically for the text in advertisements.

Answer (score 2):

Simply [one of the senses of] **text**.

> text 2  [in singular]
>
> The main body of a book or other piece of writing, as distinct from
>   other material such as notes, appendices, and illustrations. ‘the
>   pictures are clear and relate well to the text’

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/text)]

The problem is, of course, possible confusion with the other sense/s.

Comment: Slightly embarrassed I didn't think of this.  It works well, especially if I contrast it with the words "figures" and "charts" to disambiguate its meaning.